# Unity 2D Error ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I tried to create a 2D Roguelike Game.

My player sprite has to move around the map but my player sprite just moves only once and gets the error.

I try to follow this video tutorial [2D Roguelike 11 of 14 : Enemy Animator Controller](https://youtu.be/36D2pACY0XI?si=mvSqoXRq_eV8-QhT)

**This is an Error**

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index) (at <c4a10e89722742a4b5cd750857e291eb>:0)
GameManager+<MoveEnemies>d__13.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs:66)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at <affe600311164ff58161da271ceee4f0>:0)
```

**This is Script**

I try to debug it but I don't know what I've done wrong.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float turnDelay = .1f;
    public static GameManager Instance = null;
    public BoardManager boardScript;
    public int playerFoodPoints = 100;
    [HideInInspector] public bool playersTurn = true;

    private int level = 3;
    private List<Enemy> enemies;
    private bool enemiesMoving;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
            Instance = this;
        else if (Instance != this)
            Destroy(gameObject);

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        enemies = new List<Enemy> ();
        boardScript = GetComponent<BoardManager>();
        InitGame();
    }

    void InitGame()
    {
        enemies.Clear ();
        boardScript.SetupScene(level);
    }

    public void GameOver()
    {
        enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (playersTurn || enemiesMoving)
            return;
        StartCoroutine(MoveEnemies());
    }

    public void AddEnemyToList(Enemy script)
    {
        enemies.Add(script);
    }

    IEnumerator MoveEnemies()
    {
        enemiesMoving = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(turnDelay);
        if (enemies.Count == 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(turnDelay);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)
        {
            enemies[1].MoveEnemy();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(enemies[1].moveTime);
        }

        playersTurn = true;
        enemiesMoving = false;
    }

}
```

I think maybe error at here

```
 IEnumerator MoveEnemies()
 {
     enemiesMoving = true;
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(turnDelay);
     if (enemies.Count == 0)
     {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(turnDelay);
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)
     {
         enemies[1].MoveEnemy();
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(enemies[1].moveTime);
     }

     playersTurn = true;
     enemiesMoving = false;
 }
```

Comment: When you init the game you clear the enemy list and then then try to move the enemy in the first position (second enemy) of the list. It's empty, you've cleared it moments ago. Can't move something that doesn't exist.

Comment: look like a **typo**: instead of `enemies[1]` it should probably rather be `enemies[i]`

Answer (score 1):

as the error showing the ArgumentOutOfRangeException occur in line 66 of your GameManager

```
enemies[1].MoveEnemy();
```

you trying to get second element of enemies list while list has less than two object

here `for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)` you using `if` to iterate over object in enemies list but you never use `i`

i checked your tutorial link and in that video what i see is `enemies[i].MoveEnemy();`

so changing line 66 & 67 of your GameManager to this will fix your issue:

```
enemies[i].MoveEnemy();
yield return new WaitForSeconds(enemies[i].moveTime);
```